# How to Loop Recordsets and its child recrords in one loop

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I want help with the loop, this is my table Structure & Records in it. What i want is to loop records for each `U_ID` there are multiple records with the same `U_ID`.

[image]

**SQL Query**

```
Set Rs2 = con.execute("Select U_ID, stdName, Class_Code, subject, total_marks, act_marks, obt_marks, Format(submit_date,'dd-MMM-yyyy') as submit_date From res_correct ORDER BY submit_date, subject, Class_Code")
```

**My ASP CODE:**

```
If Not RS2.EOF Then

Response.write "<table width=""80%"">"& vbcrlf
Response.write "<tr>"& vbcrlf
Response.write "<td><strong>Name:</strong><span class=""underline"">"& Rs2("stdName")&" </span></td>" & vbcrlf
Response.write "<td><strong>Class:</strong> <span class=""underline"">" & Rs2("Class_Code")&" </span></td>" & vbcrlf
Response.write "<td><strong>UID:</strong> <span class=""underline"">"& Rs2("U_ID") &"</span></td>"& vbcrlf
Response.write "<td><strong>Date:</strong> <span class=""underline"">"& Rs2("submit_date") &"</span></td>"& vbcrlf
Response.write "</tr>" &vbcrlf

Response.write "<tr class=""trhead2"">" &vbcrlf
Response.write "<td>Subject</td>" &vbcrlf
Response.write "<td>Total Marks</td>" &vbcrlf
Response.write "<td>Obtained Marks</td>" &vbcrlf
Response.write "<td>Actual Marks</td>" &vbcrlf
Response.write "</tr>" &vbcrlf
Rs2.MoveFirst

Do
Response.Write "<tr class=""trhighlight"">" &vbcrlf
Response.Write "<td>"& Rs2("Subject") &" </td>" &vbcrlf
Response.Write "<td>"& Rs2("total_marks")&" </td>" &vbcrlf
Response.Write "<td>"& Rs2("obt_marks")&" </td>" &vbcrlf
Response.Write "<td>"& Rs2("act_marks")&" </td>" &vbcrlf
Response.Write "</tr>" &vbcrlf

RS2.MoveNext()

Loop Until RS2.EOF
Response.write "</table>" &vbcrlf
End If
```

**The Output Result i need is as follows:**

[image]

**Instead i'm getting this**
[image]

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the user info row in a condition and then work out when the user changes. Something like this;

```
<%
IF RS2.EOF THEN
    'No results
ELSE
    'start loop
    WHILE NOT RS2.EOF
        rowCount = rowCount + 1

        'set the first user and then work out when the user changes
        if userid="" then
            userid=RS2("U_ID")
            progress=true
        else
            if userid-RS2("U_ID") = 0 then
                progress=false
            else
                userid=RS2("U_ID")
                progress=true
            end if
        end if

        IF (progress AND rowCount > 1) THEN
            Response.write "</table>" & vbcrlf
        END IF

        'user has changed
        IF progress THEN
            Response.write "<table width=""80%"">"& vbcrlf
            Response.write "<tr>"& vbcrlf
            Response.write "<td><strong>Name:</strong><span class=""underline"">"& Rs2("stdName")&" </span></td>" & vbcrlf
            Response.write "<td><strong>Class:</strong> <span class=""underline"">" & Rs2("Class_Code")&" </span></td>" & vbcrlf
            Response.write "<td><strong>UID:</strong> <span class=""underline"">"& Rs2("U_ID") &"</span></td>"& vbcrlf
            Response.write "<td><strong>Date:</strong> <span class=""underline"">"& Rs2("submit_date") &"</span></td>"& vbcrlf
            Response.write "</tr>" &vbcrlf

            Response.write "<tr class=""trhead2"">" &vbcrlf
            Response.write "<td>Subject</td>" &vbcrlf
            Response.write "<td>Total Marks</td>" &vbcrlf
            Response.write "<td>Obtained Marks</td>" &vbcrlf
            Response.write "<td>Actual Marks</td>" &vbcrlf
            Response.write "</tr>" &vbcrlf
        END IF

        'write out user's data
        Response.Write "<tr class=""trhighlight"">" &vbcrlf
        Response.Write "<td>"& Rs2("Subject") &" </td>" &vbcrlf
        Response.Write "<td>"& Rs2("total_marks")&" </td>" &vbcrlf
        Response.Write "<td>"& Rs2("obt_marks")&" </td>" &vbcrlf
        Response.Write "<td>"& Rs2("act_marks")&" </td>" &vbcrlf
        Response.Write "</tr>" &vbcrlf

    RS2.MoveNext
    WEND
    IF progress = false THEN
        Response.write "</table>" & vbcrlf
    END IF
END IF
%>
```

You'll need to order your recordset results by the user id.

Comment: Hello Andy, thanks for the reply. I run the code you've provided and here's the result. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68407113/Stackoverflow/Screenshot-2013-11-11-15.46.01.jpg

Comment: This method might work if you change the end of your query to "...ORDER BY U_ID, submit_date, subject, Class_Code

Comment: Yes, thanks John, you'll need to order your recordset by user id

Comment: @AndyDavies thanks for the help. Now i'm getting proper output as expected. And also applied the query modifications suggested by John. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly I think you need two recordsets, one nested inside the other.

The query for the first - we'll call it rs1 - would be something like

```
"SELECT uid, studentname, submitdate FROM rescorrect ORDER BY uid"
```

and for the second - we'll call it rs2 - would be

```
"SELECT * FROM rescorrect WHERE uid = " & rs1("uid") & "ORDER BY submitdate, subject, ClassCode"
```

You could also take a look at datashaping - the really useful stuff is on page 3

https://web.archive.org/web/20210513001641/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092599-1.shtml

Comment: Thank you John, i appreciate your efforts and suggestion in the above answer :) My problem has been solved.